# Are etcdctl client connections to etcd atomic?

Tags: linux, docker, etcd

I am trying to set up a collection of docker containers and trying to emulate a cluster election process, by using etcd to store the current leader hostname with a ttl of 5 mins. I'm running a looped shell script inside every container which sleeps for 5min + random 1-9 sec, and try to create the leader key, which fails if there is an existing value, or sets a new value and the successful container becomes the new leader.

My immediate concern is, are etcdctl connections to the etcd host atomic ? What if by chance two containers connect at the same time ? And also I would appreciate suggestions on a more elegant way to implement the whole scenario.

Comment: I should mention that I understand what i'm doing is rather crude, but I am trying to avoid tackling quorum, heartbeat, split brain and other problems associated with the real deal and keep things as simple as possible.

Comment: I think you just care about whether the ```mk``` operation is atomic, not connection establish.

Comment: Yes, that is true for what I'm doing right now. By connection I meant the whole operation of mk. And as I mentioned, I am looking for a better approach than this.